# Proper closing of GreenDao Database

Tags: android, greendao

I've been looking for the proper way to close the database when using GreenDao. I've found some mentions in various places (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947068/how-to-know-all-open-connections-of-data-base-using-green-dao)), however I'm still not exactly sure how this should be done. Can anyone post a sample code for a class extending Application that properly closes and opens the database.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe check here?https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/greendao/close/greendao/tL4SPjOv7tA/JnBRRAqtORwJ

Comment: I had seen that. So basically there's no need to actually somehow close the database or session or anything like that?

Comment: thats what they say : )

Comment: I think it's best to close the SQLiteDatabase object that you create when you are done with it. I have found that otherwise it leaks if accessed in quick succession.